# DB Visualizer on Ubuntu 16.04 - java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, ubuntu, dbvisualizer

I have installed DB Vizualizer using dpkg -i and when I launch DB Visualizer from the dashboard I get an error "java.util.NoSuchElementException".

```
$ java -version
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Environment variables (set automatically by installer):

```
DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db
J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I can run it from the Terminal by **sudo dbvis** however this way of running it does not keep my connections and settings so each time I launch it again all my connections and settings are gone.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem T_T. If you don't mind, could you do me a favor? Could you pretty please type in this command:

```
vim ~/.local/share/applications/com-install4j-runtime-launcher-unixlauncher.desktop
```

This is the desktop launch configuration file for the DbVis application. For the 'Exec' variable in this file, enter the following path:

```
/opt/DbVisualizer/dbvis
```

So the '~/.local/share/applications/com-install4j-runtime-launcher-unixlauncher.desktop' file should look very similar to this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=DbVisualizer Pro 9.5.7
Icon=com-install4j-runtime-launcher-unixlauncher.png
Path=[*hey! no peeking! XD*]
Exec=/opt/DbVisualizer/dbvis
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=com-install4j-runtime-launcher-UnixLauncher
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: You are an absolute genius!!!! :)) It works!! Thank you so much!!! I will share this with DbVisualizer support as they couldn't help me with this :)

Comment: Worked for me, too. Thanks, @Desiree.

Answer (score -3):

As Desiree Wilson stated above, but the file she mentioned, at the path ~/.local/share/applications/com-install4j-runtime-launcher-unixlauncher.desktop , will be created only when you lock the program in the launcher (not before).